# XML comparison for checking whether same or different window applications

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I have two XML file sitemap.xml and mouse.xml which look like below.Here the thing is that

i need to compare sitemap.xml with mouse.xml in such a way that the tag
`<Name></Name>.`I need to compare both xml file whether the content 
coming inside `<Name></Name>` tag is same or not in c# code

Here the `<Name></Name`> tag are different means sitemap.xml contain "test
" and mouse.xml contain "exam".

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <ObjectClass>
    <Image>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Image>
    <Description />
    <Name>test</Name>
    <DefaultApp>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</DefaultApp>
    <ID>464930eb-e518-4d0c-b80b-184c97c7dd27</ID>
    <ParentClassID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002</ParentClassID>
    <DynamicPopulation>false</DynamicPopulation>
    <TimeoutPeriod>0</TimeoutPeriod>
    <Persist>false</Persist>
    <ClassVersion>1</ClassVersion>
    <Reinitialize>false</Reinitialize>
  </ObjectClass>
```

this is mouse.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
    <ObjectClass>
    <Image>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Image>
    <Description />
    <Name>exam</Name>
    <DefaultApp>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</DefaultApp>
    <ID>464930eb-e518-4d0c-b80b-184c97c7dd27</ID>
    <ParentClassID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002</ParentClassID>
    <DynamicPopulation>false</DynamicPopulation>
    <TimeoutPeriod>0</TimeoutPeriod>
    <Persist>false</Persist>
    <ClassVersion>1</ClassVersion>
    <Reinitialize>false</Reinitialize>
  </ObjectClass>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
    doc1.Load(@"c:\myproject\WindowsApplication1\sitemap.xml");
    doc2.Load(@"c:\myproject\WindowsApplication1\mouse.xml");

    XmlNodeList a = doc1.GetElementsByTagName("Name");
    XmlNodeList b = doc2.GetElementsByTagName("Name");
    if (a.Count == 1 && b.Count == 1)
    {
        if (a[0].InnerText == b[0].InnerText)
            Console.WriteLine("Equal");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
    }
```

Comment: i am getting this exception Could not find file 'F:\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\sitemap.xml'.

Comment: Hey buddy, add physical file path for your xml files. e.g c:\xyz\sitemap.xml.

Comment: i am a begginner,,can you tell me how to find physical path

Comment: i used Server.MapPath but its showing The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context F:\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form

Comment: Physical path mean the full path of sitemap.xml and mouse.xml.

Comment: how to get it,,which way we can do that

Comment: Yes got it,,right click on the xml file in solution explorer,From there take it path

Answer (score 2):

Try the Microsoft [XML diff API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

XMLUnit is awesome for xml comparison. Primarily Java based but there is a .Net port there too (I've only used the Java one): http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/